# multiple row in one row as columns (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

i have School database and i need to display report for all students and every student has multiple subject and degree in it

```
SELECT grades.student_id,   
     grades.class_id,   
     grades.course_id,   
     grades.general_total
     grades.activity
FROM grades 
WHERE  grades.class_id = 17
```

my output like it

```
student_id      class_id    course_id   general_total     activity  ....
=================================================================================
330             17              1               15         55
330             17              3               22         44
331             17              1               11         13
331             17              3               12         14
=================================================================================
```

I need output like

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
student_id  class_id    general_total for course 1       general_total for course 3            activity for course1          activity for course3     ....
=================================================================================================================================================
330             17              15                               22                                   55                           44
331             17              11                               12                                   13                           14
=================================================================================================================================================
```

That mean for every student i need to show all him degree in all courses

Comment: Google MySql pivot table. Here's one useful link: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78

Comment: If it was me, because there's no aggregation of results, I'd handle the display logic entirely within the application level code (e.g. a php loop). Just because something *can* be done doesn't mean it *should*!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT student_id, class_id
,SUM(CASE WHEN course_id = 1 
          THEN general_total ELSE 0 END) AS general_total_Course1
,SUM(CASE WHEN course_id = 3 
          THEN general_total ELSE 0 END) AS general_total_Course3
,SUM(CASE WHEN course_id = 1 
          THEN activity ELSE 0 END) AS Activity_Course1
,SUM(CASE WHEN course_id = 3 
          THEN activity ELSE 0 END) AS Activity_Course3
FROM grades
GROUP BY student_id, class_id
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01c53/3)

If you don't know the values of `course_id` use this dynamic query:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when `course_id` = ''',
      `course_id`,
      ''' then general_total END) AS `general_total_course_',
      `course_id`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM grades;

SET @sql1 = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when `course_id` = ''',
      `course_id`,
      ''' then activity END) AS `activity_Course_',
      `course_id`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql1
FROM grades;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT student_id, class_id, ', @sql,',', @sql1, '
                  FROM grades 
                   GROUP BY student_id, class_id 
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01c53/17)

Output:

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦════════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ STUDENT_ID ║ CLASS_ID ║ GENERAL_TOTAL_COURSE_1 ║ GENERAL_TOTAL_COURSE_3 ║ ACTIVITY_COURSE_1 ║ ACTIVITY_COURSE_3 ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║        330 ║       17 ║                     15 ║                     22 ║                55 ║                44 ║
║        331 ║       17 ║                     11 ║                     12 ║                13 ║                14 ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩════════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case that unknown values of `course_id` is present, a *Dynamic SQL* is much preferred:

```
-- COLUMN HEADER FOR general_total
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN course_id = ''',
               course_id,
               ''' THEN general_total END) AS ',
               CONCAT('`general_total_course_', course_id, '`')
               )) INTO @general_total
FROM grades
WHERE  class_id = 17
ORDER BY course_id;

-- COLUMN HEADER FOR activity 
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN course_id = ''',
               course_id,
               ''' THEN activity END) AS ',
               CONCAT('`general_total_activity_', course_id, '`')
               )) INTO @activity
FROM grades
WHERE  class_id = 17
ORDER BY course_id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT student_id, class_id, ', @general_total, ',
                          ', @activity, '
                   FROM   grades
                   WHERE  class_id = 17
                   GROUP  BY student_id, class_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a97a4/7)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*added extra `course_ID` without modifying the query*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/785f7/1)